# Converting a Time to 24 hour time in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I am running on DB2 and I am trying to convert a H:MI:SS AM/PM format, like this '3:33:38 PM' into 24HH:MI:SS format, like this '15:33:38'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is frequently asked. Different methods exist, cyou an use [TO_DATE](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007109.html) aka [TIMESTAMP_FORMAT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007107.html) combined with TIME or similar.

example, to create a time result

```
time(to_date('3:33:38 PM', 'HH12:MI:SS AM'))
```

which yields
`15:33:38`

Answer (score 1):

It would be unusual to store a time in Db2 as a string..

```
select timefld
from mytable
```

Might indeed return, 3:33:38 PM, but if timefld is an actual time data type, then the value return you are seeing is a function of whatever tool you're using to query Db2.

Look around in your client's config for an option to change the format used for dates and times
[image]

Note that this only affects how the UI displays the data stored in the database.

It doesn't affect the internal format used to actually store the time, nor the external format used to return the data to clients.